# vb.net listbox- Remove ALL items that DON'T contain specific text

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm working with a listbox in vb.net and am trying to remove all items from the listbox that don't contain specific text at the click of a button. Here's my code:

```
   Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ListBoxPrePublish.Items.Count - 1
        If InStr(ListBoxPrePublish.Items(i), "-8-") > 0 = False Then
            ListBoxPrePublish.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

This only removes 1 item at a time though. How can I tweak this to remove all items that don't contain "-8-" at once?

EDIT: in case anyone asks, the listbox items list is growing rather large so I'm adding a sort feature so users can widdle down their options if they want to. That's why I'm not filtering anything before adding to the listbox

Comment: Try looping in different direction `For i = ListBoxPrePublish.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1`

Comment: Thanks but "end of statement expected" when I add    To 0 Step -1

Comment: Can you post entire code modified code code for backward loop? 'Step -1' is a valid VB.Net statement. Also `String` in VB has `Contains` method so you can do your check as `If ListBoxPrePublish.Items(i).Contains("-8-") Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code for backward loop I mentioned in the comments - it should work:

```
For i as Integer = ListBoxPrePublish.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 
    If Not ListBoxPrePublish.Items(i).Contains("-8-") Then
        ListBoxPrePublish.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I see where my error was. Unfortunately, this produces the same results as my initial code. Still only deletes 1 item per button click.

Comment: Are you sure? You initial code even had "Exit For" which guaranteed only one removal. Can you step thru this code in debugger to see if condition is met and if removal is taking place?

Comment: I'm sorry Yuriy, you are correct. In my effort to not copy/paste code, I overlooked that you had removed that from your code sample. Thank you for the assistance, I appreciate it immensely. This is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not know of any `RemoveRange` type functionality. And be advised that you will need to loop through the listbox `Items` collection backwards as you remove items or you will get index exceptions, because once you remove something it will mess up the index values of all the remaining items in the iterator.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the pointer. What I find confusing is I can remove all selected items with a For Each loop, I would think being that I can do that, I should somehow be able to accomplish what I'm after